# Implementing user impersonation in Rails API + React client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, client-server, impersonation

So, I found gems like [pretender](https://github.com/ankane/pretender), [user_impersonate2](https://github.com/userimpersonate/user_impersonate2) and [switch_user](https://github.com/flyerhzm/switch_user). They all seem to accomplish the similar goal - switching `current_user` for systems like Devise, for "monolith" Rails apps.

I have a React client talking to a Rails app. The admin page is implemented directly in Rails (it's a view), and the client is separated. Currently, client makes POST requests to Devise routes that provide an `access_token` via [`devise-jwt`](https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt), and saves the token in browser's `localstorage`.

Is there a recommended way on allowing administrators to log in as users and be redirected from the admin (Rails) page to the client (React) page? Preferably with minimum changes to the frontend code, but I can make do with that.

I thought about sharing cookies via a shared root domain, but that smells of security issues to me.

I'm not sure how can I make the client app to "listen" for the token change made in the Rails app, or any similar way of changing the current user from the client's perspective.

Comment: Hi, I know it's been a while but did you manage to implement this feature? Did you maybe try any of those gems you listed above?

Comment: I don't know what your token expiration policies look like, but isn't it possible to serve the user's JWT to the admin page and have some JS on the front-end side simply make an HTTP 1.1 request with `Set-Cookie: foo_bar` or something similar? It really just depends on token expiry - unless I'm missing something.

Comment: You really don't talk about the behavior you want.  Or at least I don't get it.  Does the user have 2 windows open?  You want the client view to change when the admin view changes users?  Or do you want the user on the admin page to be redirected to the client page when they select a new user?  Or you want it to open a new window when they select a new user?  And you want the user to stick to that window only or all windows?
The behavior you want will likely affect the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't go so far as to suggest that this is recommended, but I'll tell you the basic approach that I have taken.

When building the JWT we include some key user information that allows the user to be identified from the token.  Looking at the devise-jwt docs, the simplest possible solution would be something like this:

```
def jwt_payload
  { uid: id }
end
```

Next, you've got to make sure that you can share the secret that you used to create the JWT.  I am a 12-factor fan, so our solution uses environment variables for things like this.

Finally, we read the JWT from the headers, decrypt, and lookup the user.  This assumes that you either share a database of users OR replicate users.  We built this into a module that is included in our ApplicationController.  Adapting ours, it looks something like this for the payload above:

```
module JwtTokenable
  private

  def token_user
    user_id = token_payload.dig(:uid)
    # CUSTOMIZE BELOW
    User.find(user_id) if user_id
  end

  def token_payload
    @payload ||= JWT.decode(access_token, ENV.fetch('JWT_SECRET', ''), true, { algorithm: 'HS512' })
                    .first
                    .deep_symbolize_keys
  rescue JWT::DecodeError
    return {}
  end

  def access_token
    @access_token ||= authorization_header.split.last
  end

  def authorization_header
    request.headers['Authorization'] || ''
  end
end
```

The last step for impersonation would be where the 'CUSTOMIZE BELOW' comment is.  This code just looks up the user by ID.  At that point, you might be able to leverage one of the gems that you mentioned to figure out if you need to return the user or whomever is being impersonated.